# Postfix error while sending through MS Office 365

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I have configured the Ms office 365 in postfix. But am facing the error while sending an email. Here is the log.

```
AD0C147573: lost connection with smtp.office365.com[40.97.188.242] while sending RCPT TO
Oct 30  ipostfix/cleanup[28332]: B3998475A6: message-id=<20181031080058.B3998475A6@localhost>
Oct 30  postfix/bounce[28330]: AD0C147573: sender non-delivery notification: B3998475A6

    to=<mail@example.in>, relay=smtp.office365.com[40.97.188.242]:587, delay=5, delays=0/0/0.02/5, dsn=5.7.57, status=bounced (host smtp.office365.com[40.97.188.242] said: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [0PR0102CA0006.prod.exchangelabs.com] (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

The output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = ip-10-0-0-10, localhost, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ip-10-0-0-139
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
```

Postfix running in ubuntu 16 server also MX and TXT records are created.

Edit: Postfix conf file

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ip-10-0-0-10
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = ip-10-0-0-10, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =[smtp.office365.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

I am sending email using mail.

```
echo "Test Message" | mail -s "Test Subject" abc@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

This means that the receiving mail host (office365) does not allow the "Mail From" address to use the relay server. Check first that the SASL username and password is correct.
`smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password`
Check the other requirements stated in

`https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4`

- Username/email address and password
  Enter the sign in credentials of the hosted mailbox being used For
- **Authentication**: You must be able to configure a user name and password to send email on the device.
- **Mailbox**: You must have a licensed Office 365 mailbox to send email from.

Comment: I am able to login with the same credentials in https://www.office.com/. I have posted my conf file. Please suggest if any changes need to do.

Comment: The only idea I can come up with right now is the info provides in https://o365info.com/smtp-relay-in-office-365-environment/
where it describes how to setup the office365 ExchangeAdmin Center -for access groups and users allowed to use SMTP to relay  (Part 3 – Enable the IIS SMTP relay to send mail on behalf other Email address)

Answer (score 0):

In main.cf, you may need to set the parameter smtp_pix_workarounds =

One of the Pix workarounds disables EHLO.

**disable_esmtp**
Disable all extended SMTP commands: send HELO instead of EHLO.

This feature is available in Postfix 2.4 and later. The default settings are backwards compatible with earlier Postfix versions.